# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint in sql?

Tags: c#, sql

I am using EF code first model. I have 3 tables `Teacher`, `Student` and `Address`. Each teacher and student can have multiple addresses, so the association between `Teacher_Address` and `Student_Address` is *1 to many*.

For this I wrote :

```
public class Teacher 
{
 public int Id;

 public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Student 
{
 public int Id;

 public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
 public int Id;

 public int? TeacherId { get; set; }
 public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

 public int? StudentId { get; set; }
 public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Api :

```
        //Creating 1 to * relationships b\w Teacher and Address
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(p => p.Teacher)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Addresses)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.TeacherId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        //creating 1 to * replationship b\w Student and Address
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(p => p.Student)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Addresses)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.StudentId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I can insert data for `Teacher` and for `Student` with no issue but when I try to delete any one row out of `Teacher` and `Student` then it shows the following exception :

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Address_dbo.Teacher_TeacherId". The conflict occurred in database "CodeFirst.TestContext", table "dbo.Address", column 'TeacherId'.*

Can anybody please tell me how to solve this issue and what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the relationship is backwards. Shouldn't the Teacher and Student need to reference the Address. I think the cascade will work correctly if you delete the address entry (which is not what I think you want). Try adding address id to the other entities and see if deleting works.

Something like this:

```
public class Teacher 
{
 public int Id;

 public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Student 
{
 public int Id;

 public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
 public int Id;

}
```

Fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasMany(p => p.Addresses)
                                  .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```